# RxJava - get list of result data of 2 combined requests

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, rx-java2

I have this two services:

```
private Observable<UMapsResponse> requestToServiceGetMaps(int idVenue, String accessToken) {
    return mService.getUMaps(idVenue, accessToken);
}

 private Observable<UMap> requestToServiceGetMapImageUrl(int idVenue, int idMap, String accessToken) {
    return mService.getUMap(idVenue, idMap, accessToken);
}
```

So I combined my two services like that:

```
    requestToServiceGetMaps(idVenue, accessToken)
            .flatMap(uMapsResponse -> Observable.just(uMapsResponse.getIndoorMaps()))
            .flatMapIterable(indoorMap -> indoorMap)
            .flatMap(
                    indoorMap -> requestToServiceGetMapImageUrl(idVenue, indoorMap.getId(), accessToken),
                    (indoorMap, uMap) -> Log.i(TAG, "MapsItem: " + new MapsItem(indoorMap, uMap))
            ).toList()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new SingleObserver<List<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(List<Integer> integers) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }
            });
```

So I have 2 questions:

1. Why I have List of Integer in onSuccess method ?
2. How to get list of MapsItem (indoorMap, uMap) ?

Comment: #1 is easy, you get a list of integers because the last operation in your stream is `toList()`.

Comment: Yes I Know by why exactly a list of Integer not MapsItem for example ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get a list of Integer because you are emitting Integers from the final step in your observer chain, since that is what `Log.i()` returns.

```
            ...
            .flatMap(
                    indoorMap -> requestToServiceGetMapImageUrl(idVenue, indoorMap.getId(), accessToken),
                    (indoorMap, uMap) -> new MapsItem(indoorMap, uMap)
            )
            .doOnNext( v -> Log.i(TAG, "MapsItem: " + v) )
            .toList()
            ...
```

Note that the result of the final `flatMap()` is the new `MapsItem` you were looking for.